# Questions about the proof of Riesz-Fischer Theorem in Measure Theory

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I'm learning from Stein's Real analysis, Chapter 2. When reading the **Riesz-Fischer** (pp70), I found part of the proof confusing:

> Suppose$\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of integrable functions，and is Cauchy
> in $L_1$ space$\to \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}^{+}$ s.t.
> $\forall n, m > N(\epsilon), ||f_n - f_m|| < \epsilon$ .
>
> Then choose a subseq ${f_{n_k}}$ s.t. $||f_{n_{k + 1}} - f_{n_k}||
>  \leq 2^{-k}, \forall k \geq 1$.
>
> Define $f := f_{n_1}(x) + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty (f_{n_{k+1}}(x)
>  -f_{n_{k}}(x)) $,
>
> $g := |f_{n_1}(x)| + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty (|f_{n_{k+1}}(x) -f_{n_{k}}(x)|)$
>
> Easy to see that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}g < \infty$, so $g$ is integrable。Since
> $|f| \leq g$, $f$ is integrable as well.
>
> Also, the series defining $f$ converges almost everywhere...

What does it mean by **the series defining $f$ converges almost everywhere**? How can we see that?

Comment: The series converges **absolutely** almost everywhere. Any absolutely convergent series is convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\int_{\mathbb{R}}g < \infty$, $g$ is finite almost everywhere.

It means that $|f_{n_1}(x)| + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty (|f_{n_{k+1}}(x) -f_{n_{k}}(x)|)$ converges  almost everywhere.

So, $f_{n_1}(x) + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty (f_{n_{k+1}}(x)
 -f_{n_{k}}(x)) $ converges (absolutely) almost everywhere.